# Error while searching for a string using xargs

Tags: xargs

I am trying to grep for a string as below but running into error shown below,can anyone suggest how to fix it?

```
find . | xargs grep 'bin data doesn't exist for HY11' -sl
```

Error:-

```
args: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
```

Comment: What about using -0 option like the error said?

Comment: @Kasra http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25691474/1

Comment: I think xargs is complaining about what it reads from stdin, not about the command line you show.  Check whether any of the file names return by `find` contain a single quote (`find . | grep \'`).

Comment: FYI, grep has a `--recursive` option.

Comment: @all - i updated the question but the command shared "find . | xargs grep 'bin data doesn't exist for HY11' -sl" is not running,if I add -0 option i get an error "xargs: argument line too long"

Comment: Try xargs -I {} grep <options> 'blah blah' {}. That will take care of any unmatched quotes in the stdin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grep pattern contains a quotation mark!

Use double quotes round the pattern: `"bin doesn't exist for HY11"` rather than `'bin ... HY11'`.

You also want to add `-print0` to the `find` command, and `-0` to `xargs`.

The better way is to do this all directly:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -H "bin doesn't exist for HY11" "{}" "+"
```

That doesn't even need `xargs`.

Comment: I tried "find . | xargs -I {} grep -R 'bin data doesn\'t exist for HY11' {}" its not able to escape the ' in doesn't

Comment: You need the `-0` thing too. I've updated the answer accordingly, and with something about how to avoid `xargs` completely.

Comment: Please do click the tick to select answer if it was useful.

Comment: Ah, try `\\'` instead of `\'`.

Comment: Or better, use double quotes round the pattern: `"bin doesn't exist for HY11"`

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Parallel you can run:

```
find . | parallel -X -q grep "bin data doesn't exist for HY11" -sl
```

All new computers have multiple cores, but most programs are serial in nature and will therefore not use the multiple cores. However, many tasks are extremely parallelizeable:

- Run the same program on many files
- Run the same program for every line in a file
- Run the same program for every block in a file

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

A personal installation does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel